# Perl regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

I'm reading some code that involves regular expression and having some trouble.

Can someone please explain it and give an example of text it would parse?

```
if(/\|\s*STUFF(\d+)\s*\|\s*STUFF(\d+)/) 
{
        $a = $1;
        $b = $2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One string it matches against is `|STUFF1|STUFF2`.

[YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAPE-Regex-Explain/)

```
(?-imsx:\|\s*STUFF(\d+)\s*\|\s*STUFF(\d+))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \|                       '|'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  STUFF                    'STUFF'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \|                       '|'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  STUFF                    'STUFF'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\|\s*STUFF(\d+)\s*\|\s*STUFF(\d+)
```

`\|` look for a literal pipe character `|`.

`\s*` look for any number (zero or more) whitespace characters.

`STUFF` look for the string `STUFF`

`(\d+)` look for any number of digits (one or more), and save them to `$1`.

`\s*` look for any number of whitespace characters (zero or more)

then repeat once, and save the next digit sequence in `$2`.

If the regex matches, we know that `$1` and `$2` *must* be defined (i.e. they have a value).

In that case, we assign `$1` to the variable `$a` and `$2` to `$b`.

As no explicit string to match against is provided, the `$_` variable is implicitly used.

Example text:

```
foo bar |STUFF123|STUFF456 baz bar foo
```

and

```
foo |

  STUFF0 
|STUFF1234567890bar
```